# How To: SQLite parameters with an UPDATE/WHERE command

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I'm writing my first database application. It's a C# WinForms application with a SQLite database.

I'm attempting to write a SQLite query that uses parameters with an UPDATE/WHERE command instead of an INSERT command, which is what you normally see.

Here's the link I'm using as a template. See Listing 14-2.

http://en.csharp-online.net/ASP.NET_Security_Hacks%E2%80%94Avoiding_SQL_Injection

**Can someone provide some insight on how to change the query in the link to use a UPDATE/WHERE statement instead of the INSERT statement?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that article is just pointing out that you will want to write you queries as parameterized queries to avoid sql injection attacks.  So the query logic is the same as you would normally write but instead of using string concatenation to put your dynamic values in you use variables following the syntax "@someVariableName" and then you add your dynamic values in as parameters on the sqlCommand object.

Here is a link for a walk through on how to do this for SQLite:  [Parameterized Queries](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parametrized_SQL_statement#C.23)

EDIT:  Had to find a new reference for this answer as old reference died.

Comment: How is this the correct answer when the link doesnt work? Annoying.

Comment: @MatthewPitts I updated the link.  Before being annoyed maybe you should look at the date that this was answered (3.5 years ago) and realize that sometimes pages get removed and links break.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can update database with SQLiteDataAdapter Update function.

```
cmdSQLite = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM TableName", connectionSQLite);
   daSQLite = new SQLiteDataAdapter();
   daSQLite.SelectCommand = cmdSQLite;
   dsSQLite = new DataSet();               
   daSQLite.Fill(dsSQLite, "TableName");
   dsSQLite.Tables["TableName"].Rows[NumberOfRowToChange]["ColumnName"] = somevalue;
   //...
   daSQLite.Update(dsSQLite, "TableName");
```